# Habilitar suporte PDO Firebird ao PHP

Tags: php, pdo, firebird, mac

Não consigo instalar suporte ao Firebird PDO no PHP. 
Minha máquina está rodando Mac Os Sierra.
Já pesquisei sobre macports e homebrew e eles não oferecem suporte.
Alguns posts antigos não explicam detalhadamente como resolver esse problema.
Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Qual a versão do seu php? Já tentou buscar no PECL?

Comment: Sim, busquei e encontrei, mas não sei usar o arquivo compactado fornecido, você teria algum material para me direcionar na instalação?
https://pecl.php.net/package/PDO_FIREBIRD

Comment: MAMP pré-compilado? Ou compilou tudo na mão? Se compilou assim também pode compilar a extensão PDO para Firebird. Estranhamente eu tinha certeza que isto vinha "pronto" nos pré-compilados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução que encontrei foi criar um ambiente mais próxima da realidade, ou seja, criei um servidor linux e instalei tudo o que precisava.